# USB to UART converter is lagging

Tags: drivers, usb, serial-port

I have a USB to UART converter with CH341A chip on it. This device can be used as a USB to UART converter, as a 24/25 chip programmer and as a USB to PARALLEL converter.

The problem is with the UART converter. I can use it without any problems in Windows (drivers are required though), but not in Ubuntu. I shorted RX and TX wires to test the converter and in minicom. <strike>I could see what I've written, but not instantaneously. I also tested it on an Ovislink router. I was able to read the output but the delays blocked the last lines the router was printing. When I try to write something I somehow have to refresh the minicom console.</strike> **EDIT: Actually, the last 32 characters don't show up!**

What happens in minicom: (not 32 characters, this was a screenshot; the console was moving very fast)
[image: minicom]

Video version of the problem:
[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3fqD4kLI3uM)

So basically I'm not able to read the last 32 characters and I'm not able to correctly write to the terminal. I repeat I can use this device correctly in Windows so it has to be a driver problem.

**Do you know any way to fix this? Custom driver? Patch? Anything that would make this work would help.**

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, but this is also happening on Debian Wheezy and other Ubuntu versions (probably using the same driver).

dmesg:

```
[ 1840.468078] usb 5-1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using uhci_hcd
[ 1840.622112] usb 5-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=5523
[ 1840.622120] usb 5-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[ 1840.625187] ch341 5-1:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
[ 1840.638224] usb 5-1: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 006: ID 1a86:5523 QinHeng Electronics CH341 in serial mode, usb to serial port converter
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Don't post screenshot of messages! Copy-paste them. We need to be able to read them and search inside them. **Always copy-paste error messages and logs**.

Comment: Sorry! Will remember that & edit ASAP. There's not much info in the second screenshot though.

Comment: I edited my question. Hope it helps you!